# How to force repartitioning in a spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed

I have many spark dataframes on which I need to do the following:

```
1) load a single spark dataframe
2) select rows from it
3) merge it with all of the previous spark dataframes
```

Now, each of the above operations requires a different numberof partitions.  The selecting rows requires many partitions, like 100 partitions.  The merging requires very few partitions, like 10 partitions.

So, I really want it to work like this:

```
1) load a single spark dataframe
1.5) repartition into 100 partitions
2) select rows from it
2.5) repartition into 10 partitions
3) merge it with all of the previous spark dataframes
```

Now, how do I force this to repartition in between steps 1 and 2 and in between 2 and 3?

I know that when I call `data = data.repartition(7)` it is lazily evaluated, and so it only repartitions when it is actually saving.

So, I have been doing it like this:

```
1) load a single spark dataframe
1.5) repartition into 100 partitions
1.75) `df.count()` *just* to force materialization
2) select rows from it
2.5) repartition into 10 partitions
2.75) `df.count()` *just* to force materialization
3) merge it with all of the previous spark dataframes
```

Is there a better way to force it to repartition in between here?  Is there a better way than running `count()` on the dataframe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As all transformations of dataframes in spark are lazily evaluated you need to perform an action to actually perform the transformations. Currently there are no other way to force the transformations.

All available dataframe actions can be found in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) (look under *actions*). In your case, instead of using `count()` to force the transformation you could use `first()` which should be significantly cheaper.

In step 2.5 you could replace the `repartition()` with `coalesce()` as it will avoid a full shuffle. This is often advantageous when the new number of partitions is less than before, since it will minimize the data movement.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question about what happens if you do not use any action and simply do: 1) repartition, 2) spark dataframe transform, 3) repartition. Due to optimizations spark performs on the transformations it seems to not always be the case that this order is followed. I made a small test program to test it out:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array((1.0,"a"),(2.0,"b"),(3.0,"c"),(1.0,"d"),(2.0,"e"),(3.0,"f"))).toDF("x", "y")
val df1 = df.repartition(10).filter($"x" =!= 1.0).repartition(5).filter($"y" =!= "b")
df1.explain(true)
```

This returns information about how the dataframe is computed.

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter NOT ('y = b)
+- Repartition 5, true
   +- Filter NOT (x#5 = 1.0)
      +- Repartition 10, true
         +- Project [_1#2 AS x#5, _2#3 AS y#6]
            +- LogicalRDD [_1#2, _2#3]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
x: double, y: string
Filter NOT (y#6 = b)
+- Repartition 5, true
   +- Filter NOT (x#5 = 1.0)
      +- Repartition 10, true
         +- Project [_1#2 AS x#5, _2#3 AS y#6]
            +- LogicalRDD [_1#2, _2#3]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Repartition 5, true
+- Project [_1#2 AS x#5, _2#3 AS y#6]
   +- Filter ((NOT (_1#2 = 1.0) && isnotnull(_2#3)) && NOT (_2#3 = b))
      +- LogicalRDD [_1#2, _2#3]

== Physical Plan ==
Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(5)
+- *Project [_1#2 AS x#5, _2#3 AS y#6]
   +- *Filter ((NOT (_1#2 = 1.0) && isnotnull(_2#3)) && NOT (_2#3 = b))
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[_1#2,_2#3]
```

As can be seen here, the `repartition(10)` step is not included and seems to have been removed during the optimization.

Comment: But is there any way to avoid useless operations like `first()` when I really don't care what it outputs from that?  I just want it to repartition, but I don't care about what it actually outputs.  Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: You are unfortunately required to perform an action on the dataframe to apply all transformations, so currently there is no way to avoid it. Added some information to the answer.

Comment: @Sother Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  So, it seems like there really is no easy way to do this.  I wonder if `cache` would help here, since I need to materialize the data twice (since every time I call `first()`) it will materialize the data.  Do you think `cache` is a good idea to do here in between the repartitions?

Comment: @Sother Yes, you should be able to decrease the running time by calling `cache()` on the dataframe as it will make subsequent actions on the data significantly faster. `cache()` itself will only mark the data as persistent until an action is performed, so add it before calling `first()`.

Comment: But if the table is too big to fit in memory, will cache still work?  @Shaido?

Comment: @Sother Using `cache()` will not work in that case, however, you could use `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_ONLY)` which will use both memory and disk storage together. `cache()` is actually an alias for `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)` and will hence only use the RAM memory.

Comment: I see thank you. But if I have something like 1) repartition, 2) spark dataframe transform, 3) repartition, then those operations will still happen in exactly that order - correct?  Even though they are lazily evaluated ...???

Comment: @Sother That seems not to always be the case. I made a small test and included it in the answer.